# Unity Error Occurred While Resolving Packages And Game Mode Doesn't Work Suddenly

Tags: unity-game-engine, package, game-engine, unity-editor

I never ran into this problem before while building unity projects.

[1] Yesterday, I decided to update my unity hub to newer version, and now all of a sudden,
I keep getting this error and my packages are not loading into the editor workspace.

[2] Additionally, anytime I try and enter into game mode unity will suddenly stop and bounce me back to editor mode (never happened before). I am very lost why this is happening, and even my past projects that worked fine seem to be affected as well. Cannot run them within unity now. :(

All help is greatly appreciated!

-So far I have been just looking to make sure my unity apps are in the folder of that address - and they are, looking for direction.

Comment: Hm unless you also updated to a new Unity version it seems odd that things suddenly don't work. What are the exact errors you get? You could also look into the error logs of hub and editor to hopefully find more information

Comment: `Additionally, anytime I try and enter into game mode` .. wait I thought packages don't load .. then why can you even enter play mode?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help you if you include the exact error message in your question.

I assume it is this:

```
  Cannot fetch authorization code. User access token is expired or invalid. You may need to sign out and sign in again. [Unknown].
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

If so, log out in Hub and log in again. This happens either when updating Unity Hub or with bigger Windows updates for me.